# Packing island removes overlapping

Tags: uv

I am following hard surface tutorial from BlenderBros. In video, unwrap one side and mirror it to other. That way, it preserves texture space and textel density is higher. Later in video, he applied mirror, and went to uv editing and average island scale and packed it. After that, those mirrored parts were still overlaping each other. However, in my case, when I do that - with Blender island packing or Uv Packer, it separates those parts and they are not overlapping anymore. How can I keep them stacked? Notice he didn't pin them, so neither do I.

On picture one you can see my model with UV unwrap. You can see those parts of mesh which are selected on picture two, they both share same texture space - they are stacked.  However, if I pack them to use texture space as much as possible,  it separates them and they are not overlapping anymore. I want to keep them overlapped but still be able to pack islands.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to users if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Comment: You are right. Thanks, I uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UV Packmaster addon has such a feature, I use it for a long time
https://youtu.be/xuGzSsgnwS4?t=65

Comment: This sounds great, but it costs. I assume it's worth it tho.

Comment: Totally worth, yes. Im sure there are less costy or even free packing addons, up to you to research and choose from, but this is the best.
Just dont expect UV unwrapping process to be made by default blender tools if its going to be any complex. Using addons is essential.